# VBA export multiple worksheets to new workbook

Tags: vba

Suppose I have a workbook1.xlsm with multiple worksheets and full of various formulas. I want to create a new workbook2.xlsx which would maintain the formatting as workbook1 but in all the cells,they would be values instead of formulas.
Only looking to export 4 out of 20+ worksheets from workbook1.

The VBA code below gives me the 4 sheets, leaves the formulas on first two  worksheets, does a paste special on worksheet 3 and just values on worksheet 4.

**My problem lies with Sheet 3 - I have columns with conditional formatting to convert Dollars to Euros and the dollar sign changes from the Euro Dollar sign back to the US Dollar sign. What am I missing? I am so close...**

```
Private Sub IntlSaveAsXLSX_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wbNew As Workbook
Worksheets(Array("Charter-IICE", "High Level Requirements", "IICE +- 50% Summary - INTL", "Proposal-Financials")).Copy
Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
With wbNew

With .Worksheets(3).UsedRange
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End With

With .Worksheets(4).UsedRange
.Value = .Value

End With

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="GISG-INTL-COST-MODEL-OUTPUT-CD.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Possibly a stupid question: *why would you use conditional formatting to change $ to €?* And can you give some example of what these format conditions/rules are?